# Maven build corrupts bash scripts?

Tags: bash, maven

We have application. As part of application - we have set of bash-scripts.

Sctips now are in tar-archive:

```
$ ls -l manager/
total 3076
-rwx------+ 1 Administrators Domain Users 3123200 Jan  8 15:47 manager.tar
```

Then, after **TeamCity** build, **Maven** creates jar-file like "*manager.jar*" which includes "*manager.tar*" inside.

After unpack jar and then tar - all works.

But!

If put bash-scripts without pack them in to tar-archive - after build and unpack jar-file - I always got very odd error:

```
$ ./manager.sh -h
: No such file or directory

$ bash -x manager.sh
+ $'\r'
: command not foundne 2:
+ $'\r'
: command not foundne 10:
'anager.sh: line 11: syntax error near unexpected token `{
'anager.sh: line 11: `setbase () {
```

Although - both `manager.sh` scripts (from both builds) looks same (`diff` && `vimdiff`).

**UPD**

When removing all 'newlines' in script - it seems to be work, little example:

```
setbase () { if [ "$1" = "SIT" ]; then
```

and then execution with `-xv`:

```
setbase () { if [ "$1" = "SIT" ]; then
  export BASEDIR="/home/user/APP"
  export smem="32G"
  export xmem="32G"
elif [ "$1" = "DEV" ]; then
manager/manager.sh: line 13: syntax error near unexpected token `elif'
'manager/manager.sh: line 13: `elif [ "$1" = "DEV" ]; then
```

But **VIM** doesn't show any symbols like `^M`, also - both file in same encoding:

(this one work)

```
$ file -ib /home/user/APP/manager/manager.sh
text/x-java charset=us-ascii
```

(this one - no)

```
$ file -ib manager/manager.sh
text/x-java charset=us-ascii
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is DOS line endings. This might be related to the jar packing or your new scripts might just be the only DOS line ending files you have. In either case fix that.

Comment: I thought about it - but seems no... TeamCity buildAgents works under Linux; scripts doesn't contain ^M symbols or like it...
But - there is really problem with special symbols - newline... If remove all 'newlines' in script - it almost works.

Comment: `$'\r'` is a DOS line-ending artifact. So is `: command not foundne 10:` (which is the error overwriting itself). Those files have DOS line endings. If the originals didn't then something (possibly jar creation) is converting them.

Comment: Wow... Really... I just... even with `:set list` - vim doesn't display `\r`... Thus - I can't remove them. And, of course, then question - from where it's appear at all?

Comment: If the line endings are all consistent then vim hides them and treats the file like a DOS line-ending file (`:echo &ff`). If they are inconsistent then you see `^M` on lines where they exist. Use `:set ff=unix` or `dos2unix` to convert.

Comment: `:set ff` in VIM saved my lofe :-) Thanks, @Etan.

Comment: can we emulate this behaviour in maven @setevoy while building. I don't want to do set ff=unix everytime deploying component